# linux permission for windows mounted partition

Tags: linux

I have installed windows 7 and linux opensuse in my laptop. In linux the windows is mounted under /windows/A OR B OR C OR D

When ever i write or do a touch in any of this location it says `permission denied`

The permission for /windows on running ls -l on root partition is as follows :

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root users      32768 Nov 12 11:00 Windows
```

what should i do to get the permissions for writing or deleting a file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a member of the group `users`, just use a `chmod g+w /windows` to add the write right to the members of the group `users`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with all users in opensuse having the ability to write and read the file system, the easiest way to handle this is to put in a "umask" of 0000 in your /etc/fstab for this filesystem, and then unmount and remount it (or reboot).  This will mount it with read write and execute permissions for all users.  If you google for "fstab" you should get plenty of instructions on how to do this.  In summary, you use sudo to open /etc/fstab in any text editor and in the fourth column (the one marked "options") add in "umask=0000".